# Angular4 Modal dialog Issue

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I am using Angular 4. I am trying to bring a pop up in my application using `ngx-modal-dialog`.

I am using IE11 browser. Below is my code:

In the ParentPageComponent.ts file, `openNewDialog()` function is defined as below:

```
openNewDialog(){
    this.modalService.openDialog
    (
        this.viewRef, 
        {
            title: 'Some modal title',childComponent: SimpleModalComponent
        }
    );
}
```

The constructor of ParentPageComponent.ts file is defined as

```
constructor(modalService: ModalDialogService, viewRef: ViewContainerRef){}
```

I have added the `entryComponents` in the app.module.ts file as

```
entryComponents:[SimpleModalComponent]
```

I am calling the `openNewDialog` function from ParentPageComponent.html page.

I am not able to bring the pop up and getting the following error when invoking `openNewDialog` method from parent page.

> TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialogInit'

Any help on detecting the issue will be great help.

Comment: Can you please share the code of `SimpleModalComponent`

Comment: In case you mention a library not part of the standard sdk (ngx-modal-dialog), please provide a link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://github.com/Greentube/ngx-modal#methods-1), You need to implement `IModalDialog` and you need to define `dialogInit` within your `ModalComponent`.

Check this example from docs

```
class MyModalComponent implements IModalDialog {
  actionButtons: IModalDialogButton[];

  constructor() {
    this.actionButtons = [
      { text: 'Close' }, // no special processing here
      { text: 'I will always close', onAction: () => true },
      { text: 'I never close', onAction: () => false }
    ];
  }

  dialogInit(reference: ComponentRef<IModalDialog>, options: Partial<IModalDialogOptions<any>>) {
    // no processing needed
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.